# how to add another form in current form in codeigniter?

Tags: php, codeigniter

```
form.php

<html>
<head>
<title>Welcome to SmartSage</title>
<?php echo validation_errors(); ?>

<body>
<form id='myform' action="" method="POST">


<h5>Username:</h5>
<input type="text" name="username" value="" size="50" />

<h5>Password:</h5>
<input type="password" name="passwd" value="" size="50" />

<h5>Security question:</h5><select name="securityq">
<option value="1">What is your house no?</option>
<option value="2">Who is your fav teacher?</option>
</select>
<input type="text" name="securitya" value="" size="50" />



<br>
<input type="submit" value="Login" id="submit" />&nbsp&nbsp
<a href="/`views/signup.php"><input type="button" value="Sign Up!" id="signup" /></a>

</form>
</body>
</html>
```

This is my current form coding... now my objective is to redirect from this form to signup form when user clicks "signup" button...i hv tried above code but its not working...pls help me

Views folder contains /views/signup.php /views/form.php

Thank you!!

Comment: This question appears to be off-topic because you do not show a basic understanding of the problem

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can do in two ways. You have to redirect to signup page. You can't redirect to view file directly. Here signup is controller name. If yu have your signup in another controller then you have to call as `site_url("controller_name/signup");` in below code.

```
<a href="<?php echo site_url("signup.php");?>"><input type="button" value="Sign Up!" id="signup" /></a>
```

or  remove `a` tag and call via JS.

```
<input type="button" value="Sign Up!" id="signup" onclick = "window.location='<?php echo site_url("signup.php"); ?>'" />
```

Comment: where is signup function exist? In same controller? See my updated answer.

Comment: Should i have to load signup.php in controller??

Comment: what is url you are seeing currently? I mean when you load old form.

Comment: better add your controller as well.

Comment: I am new to codeigniter...i haven't created signup function..where should i create it?

Comment: <?php if ( ! defined('BASEPATH')) exit('No direct script access allowed');

class Welcome extends CI_Controller {

 
 public function index()
 {
                
  $this->load->helper(array('form', 'url'));
                 
                $this->load->library('form_validation');                
                

                    $this->load->view('form');

 }
}

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/46597/discussion-between-kumar-v-and-john)